# is there any way to obtain the callable's argument list and then use it as parameter pack in template?

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, sfinae

callable should be any function pointer, std::function or lambda. I want to obtain their argument list and use them as parameter pack:

```
template <typename callable_T>
class callback2_t
{
public:
    using callable_t = callable_T;
    using ret_T = some_magic<callable_T>::ret_t;
    using data_T = the_first_type<argTs>;
    ...
    static ret_T _callback(some_magic<callable_T>::argTs... args);
};
```

The purpose is to simplify follow templates to make it work for all kind of callable without creating alias:

```
// other library only accept function pointer as callback, I want to wrap it to remove the callback when data go out of scope.

template <typename callable_T, typename ret_T, typename data_T, typename ...arg_Ts>
class callback_t
{
    using callable_t = callable_T;
public:
    callback_t(const char* signal, callable_t callable, data_T data)
            : f_{std::move(callable)}, data_{std::move(data)}
    {
        std::cout << signal << " " << typeid(callable).name() << std::endl;
        //register_callback(signal, _callback, this);

    }
    ~callback_t()
    {
        //unregister_callback(signal);
    }
    void test_callback(arg_Ts... args)
    {
        _callback(args..., this);
    }
private:
    callable_t f_;
    data_T data_;
    static ret_T _callback(arg_Ts... args, callback_t * self)
    {
        return self->f_(&self->data_, args...);
    }
};

// I donot want convert function pointer to std::function
// if possible. std::function is a heavy class.
template <typename ret_T, typename data_T, typename ...arg_Ts>
using fp_callback_t = callback_t<ret_T(*)(void *, arg_Ts...), ret_T, data_T, arg_Ts...>;

template <typename ret_T, typename data_T, typename ...arg_Ts>
using func_callback_t = callback_t<std::function<ret_T(void *, arg_Ts...)>, ret_T, data_T, arg_Ts...>;
```

We can use the template like this:

```
struct A{float x;};
struct B{int x;};
struct C{uint x;};
int func1(void * data, A* a)
{
    auto c = reinterpret_cast<C*>(data);
    std::cout<< a->x << ", " << c->x << std::endl;
    return a->x + c->x;
}

void func2(void *data, B* b, C* c)
{
    auto a = reinterpret_cast<A*>(data);
    std::cout << b->x << ", " << c->x << ", " << a->x << std::endl;
}
int main()
{
    A a1{-10.5f};
    B b1 {5};
    C c1{300};
    auto callback1 = fp_callback_t<int, C, A*>("signal1", &func1, c1);
    callback1.test_callback(&a1);
    auto callback2 = fp_callback_t<void, A, B*, C*>("signal2", &func2, a1);
    callback2.test_callback(&b1, &c1);
    std::function<int(void*, A*)> fc1 = [=](void* data, A* a){
        auto c = reinterpret_cast<C*>(data);
        std::cout<< a->x << ", " << c->x << ", " << a1.x << std::endl;
        return (int)a1.x;
    };
    std::function<void(void*, B*, C*)> fc2 = [=](void* data, B* b, C* c){
        auto a = reinterpret_cast<A*>(data);
        std::cout << b->x << ", " << c->x << ", " << a->x << ", " << c1.x << std::endl;
    };
    auto callback3 = func_callback_t<int, C, A*>("signal3", fc1, c1);
    callback3.test_callback(&a1);
    auto callback4 = func_callback_t<void, A, B*, C*>("signal4", fc2, a1);
    callback4.test_callback(&b1, &c1);
    return 0;
}
```

The out put is:

```
signal1 PFiPvP1AE
-10.5, 300
signal2 PFvPvP1BP1CE
5, 300, -10.5
signal3 NSt3__18functionIFiPvP1AEEE
-10.5, 300, -10.5
signal4 NSt3__18functionIFvPvP1BP1CEEE
5, 300, -10.5, 300
```

The deduction should work without specialize template parameters explicitly; I want to avoid alias; It should work with function pointer, std::function and lambda; the callable_t should be as it is given instead of casting all of them to std::function. like following:

```
auto callback1 = callback2_t("signal1", &func1, c1);
callback1.test_callback(&a1);
auto callback2 = callback2_t("signal2", &func2, a1);
callback2.test_callback(&b1, &c1);
std::function<int(void*, A*)> fc1 = [=](void* data, A* a){
    auto c = reinterpret_cast<C*>(data);
    std::cout<< a->x << ", " << c->x << ", " << a1.x << std::endl;
    return (int)a1.x;
};
auto callback3 = callback2_t("signal3", fc1, c1);
callback3.test_callback(&a1);
auto lambda1 = [=](void* data, B* b, C* c){
    auto a = reinterpret_cast<A*>(data);
    std::cout << b->x << ", " << c->x << ", " << a->x << ", " << c1.x << std::endl;
};
auto callback4 = callback2_t("signal4", lambda1, a1);
callback4.test_callback(&b1, &c1);
```

Comment: One can specialize for `std::function`, and a function pointer, and deduce the parameter types and the return value. It's a good question how to do this for closures, can't quickly think of what to do about those, off the top of my head...

Comment: Even for std::function and function pointer, how do I do the trick `ret_T _callback(some_magic<callable_T>::argTs... args);`?

Comment: For a function or function pointer, no problem. But arbitrary callables may accept *different* argument lists (like several `operator()` overloads). That’s not the case for lambdas but they use the machinery capable of that AFAIK...

Comment: @numzero can you provide an example about how to do this for just function and function pointer? It will also be very helpful. To clarify, I do not want *arbitrary* callable. I just want 3 of them stated in first sentence.

Comment: @Wang: But lambdas *are* "arbitrary callables". A lambda in C++ is nothing more than an easy way to make a class with an `operator()` overload. There is no way to tell the difference between a type that is a true "lambda" and a type that has an `operator()` overload.

Comment: @numzero lambdas can do it too via `auto`: `[](auto... args) { (std::cout << ... << args); }`

Comment: That will be a template lambda them, won’t it? That’s another story...

Comment: @numzero Yup. What is the parameter list of its `operator()`? Answer: Anything you want it to be. Now, maybe you want to say "only in the case where operator() is unambiguous", in which case you can inspect the parameters of `&callable_t::operator()`. If the operator is overloaded, then you get an error. On the other hand, it is common to use `auto` in lambda parameter lists to save typing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to deduce the parameters at all. Just let the template soak them up and forward them to the callable.

```cpp
template <typename callable_T, typename data_T>
class callback_t
{
    using callable_t = callable_T;
public:
    callback_t(const char* signal, callable_t callable, data_T data)
            : f_{std::move(callable)}, data_{std::move(data)}
    {
    }

    template<typename...arg_Ts>
    auto test_callback(arg_Ts... args)
    {
        return _callback(this, args...);
    }
private:
    callable_t f_;
    data_T data_;
    template<typename...arg_Ts>
    static auto _callback(callback_t * self, arg_Ts... args)
    {
        return self->f_(&self->data_, args...);
    }
};
```

Works great even if `operator()` is overloaded:

```cpp
int test()
{
    callback_t cc("test", [](auto x, auto y){ return *x + y;}, 42);
    return cc.test_callback(9); // returns 42 + 9 = 51
}
```

Comment: The major problem in my question is actually the signature of _callback need to by `<arg_Ts..., void *>` which is not deductible. As I stated, it is the requirement of libs from others which I cannot change. If this is not the requirement, surely just let the template soak it will be the most neat way to do this.

Comment: I wonder if I can take advantage of tuple. `using TypesTuple = std::tuple<Types...>;` then some how use the last type inside tuple. Then we can get rid of the data_T

Comment: Yes, you can stuff the types into a tuple and then use `tuple_element_t<tuple_size_v<TypesTuple> - 1, TypesTuple>` to pluck out the type. Really, the `data_T` was never needed. You could just capture the data into the lambda.

Comment: @RaymondChen Sorry to bother you, or if I've broken protocol by pinging you here, but a question came up recently in which I referenced/quoted one of your blogs. You *may* like to offer some insights ... it's [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61510204/10871073).

Answer (score 0):

That was an interesting quiz =) The trick was to pass pointer to `lambda::operator()` and let type deduction work:

```
template <typename Ret, typename ... Args>
struct Callback {
    Callback() {
        std::cout << "Created " << typeid(*this).name() << "\n";
    }
};

template <typename Ret, typename ... Args>
Callback<Ret, Args...> create_callback(std::function<Ret (Args...)> const &fn) {
    std::cout << "Function!\n";
    return Callback<Ret, Args...>();
}

template <typename Ret, typename ... Args>
Callback<Ret, Args...> create_callback(Ret (*fn)(Args...)) {
    std::cout << "Function pointer!\n";
    return Callback<Ret, Args...>();
}

template <typename Lambda, typename Ret, typename ... Args>
Callback<Ret, Args...> create_callback_lambda(Lambda const &, Ret (Lambda::*)(Args...) const) {
    std::cout << "Lambda!\n";
    return Callback<Ret, Args...>();
}

template <typename Callable>
auto create_callback(Callable const &c) {
    return create_callback_lambda(c, &Callable::operator());
}
```

Comment: @Wang did you look at this example? Yes it uses functions instead of a second type, but that shouldn’t be a problem. The `create_callback` function may be used without template arguments, both Ret and Args are deduced automatically (for lambdas and alike, `create_callback_lambda` is what gets the decuded types). From this point, you *do* have all the types so can build any solution on this.